# Как получить имя узла?

Tags: javascript

Когда в консоли пишешь

```
console.dir(
  d.getElementById("blog-container")
)
```

он возвращает объект с таким вот названием `section#blog-container`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как получить это название ?

Мне это нужно для делегированных событий, что бы я мог писать в функцию селектор, а при событии функция брала такой селектор у элемента и сравнивала.

Пример:

```
on("click", "section#blog-container", function () { 
  ДЕйствие
})
```

в идеале конечно хотелось бы заставить работать селекторы такого типа `body > div > header > bottom`, но у меня нет вообще никаких идей. Если подскажите что нибудь буду рад)

p.s. Я не использую jQuery, я делаю в некотором роде его клон. Задача стоит сделать функцию делегированных событий. Конкретно проблема заключается в удобном отлавливании событий вот по таким селекторам "`.texteditor > header > button`". и само событие вешается на body т.к. весь сайт ajax

Comment: `on("click", "section#blog-container", function () { ... })` выглядит так, что Вы используете jQuery. Так ли это? Хотите ли Вы использовать селекторы jQuery или нет? Есть базисные DOM методы `getElementById`, `getElementsByClassName`, `getElementsByTagName` и `querySelectorAll`, `querySelector`. Последние позваляют поиск используя сложные селекторы. jQuery предлагает использовать селекторы в конструкторе и в `.find` методе. Так что очень важно уточнить, используети ли Вы jQuery или нет. Кроме того, важно понять Вашу цель - сконструировать *быстрый селектор* или длинный и точный, но медленный?

Comment: Нет, я не использую jQuery, я делаю в некотором роде его клон. Задача стоит сделать функцию делегированных событий. Конкретно проблема заключается в удобном отлавливании событий вот по таким селекторам ".texteditor > header > button". и само событие вешается на body т.к. весь сайт ajax

Comment: и `on` в конструкции `on("click", "section#blog-container", function () { ... })` - эта Ваша собственная функция?

Comment: Да, она ещё не написана, это вид обращения к ней

Comment: `on("click", ".texteditor > header > button", function () { ... })` - это плохой пример, который подразумевает `delegated events`, которые работают медленнее. Но в общем, мне кажется, что **`querySelectorAll`** - это то, что вы ищите.

Comment: Нет querySelectorAll мне не подходит т.к. при Ajax добавлении контента на новых элементах не будет срабатывать событие, т.к. для них оно бонаьно ещё не будет назначен, вся сложность и заключается  в том что необходимо использовать делегирование

Comment: если Вы предложите конструкцию, которая будет **отслеживать** новые элементы, то у вас получится *очень медленная* конструкция. Быструю конструкцию можно сделав регистрируя `click` только на родительском элементе(ах). За счет "event bubbling", см. [здесь](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events) колонку "Bubbles", `click` будет пропагондироваться наверх до `body`. В event handle можно тестировать подходит ли `event.target` под селектор типа ".texteditor > header > button". Для этого можно использовать быструю функию `querySelectorAll`.

Comment: Так что вы предлагает каждый раз при клике находить все элементы ".texteditor > header > button" с помощью querySelectorAll и в цикле смотреть является ли event.target одним из набора возвращённым querySelectorAll, я правильно понял ? Не лучше ли уже тогда забыть про делегирование и применять событие непосредственно на каждый элемент возвращённый querySelectorAll, и проводить такую операцию каждый раз при обновлении контента ?

Comment: Этого нельзя делать по нескольким причинам. Во-первых, Вы сначала выполняете `$("body").on("click", ".texteditor > header > button", function () { /*основной handle*/ })`. Это регистрирует event handle (*вспомогательный*) на **одном элементе** `body`. При этом `body` может быть почти пуст. Потом `body` динамически изменяется, неизвесто кем и когда. Позже, после клика куда-то внутри `body` он пропогандируется до регистрированного *вспомогательного* handle'а на `body` и вам нужно определить, не нужно ли выполнить *основной* handle.

Comment: Это нужно сделать только если `event.target` удовлетворяет селектору `".texteditor > header > button"`. Такая проверка весьма трудоемкая. Нужно написать parser на общего вида селектор. Альтернативно можно вызвать `querySelectorAll` и проверить включен ли `event.target` в коллекцию элементов, возвращенных методом `querySelectorAll`. Так или иначе все будет работать на так быстро, но обычно селектор простой и `querySelectorAll` возващает овин или несколько элементов.

Comment: Но я лично никогда не использую в своем коде конструкцию типа `$("body").on("click", ".texteditor > header > button", function () { ... })` из-за ее скорости.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34939/discussion-between-kirpich643-and-oleg).

Answer (score 1):

Я как то раз решал похожую задачу. Вот что вышло:

```
function(el){
    if(el==document){
        //Костыль(
        return {
            selector:'document'
        };
    }
    if(el==window){
        //Костыль(
        return {
            selector:'window'
        };
    }
    var selector=null;
    if(el.id){
        selector='#'+el.id;
    }else{
        if(el.className){
            selector='.'+el.className.split(' ').join('.');
        }else{
            //Ох..ну ничего,прорвемся.
            selector=el.tagName;//tagName то у тебя точно есть.
            if(el.name){
                selector+='[name='+el.name+']';
            }
        }
    }
    if(!selector)console.error('Cant build selector!',el);
    var index=$(selector).index(el);
    return {
        selector: selector,
        index: index
    }
}
```

Как видите, здесь кроме селектора есть еще index - т.е. номер конкретного элемента в списке элементов с таким селектором. Позволяет точно определять любой элемент на странице.